# how to use data-jfiler-files in jquery filer?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-filer

i have used jquery filer, i have tried to EDITMODE in jquery filer using `data-jfiler-files` attribute.

but i didn't get result.. what mistake i did?

PHP

```
<?php
    $dummyarr1 = array();
    foreach($templateVal_array['media_src'] as $Ind){
        $dummyarr = array();

        $dummyarr['name'] = $Ind['oname'];
        $dummyarr['size'] = (int)str_replace(',', '', $Ind['size']);
        $dummyarr['type'] = "image/jpg";
        $dummyarr['file'] = "http://localhost/datacapture/evt/media_src/".str_replace(' ', '_', $Ind['fname']).".".$Ind['ext'];

        $dummyarr1[] = $dummyarr;
    }
?>

<input type="file" name="media_src[]" class="filepicker-custom" data-jfiler-files = <?php echo json_encode($dummyarr1); ?> multiple="multiple" />
```

I have also tried to following way It has worked fine

```
$(".filepicker-custom").filer({
    limit: 3,
    maxSize: 3,
    extensions: ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "txt", "docx", "doc", "pdf"],
    showThumbs: true,
    addMore: true,
    files: [{
      name: "appended_file.jpg",
      size: 777835,
      type: "image/jpg",
      file: "http://localhost/datacapture/evt/media_src/Avg_rain_fall-58bfd786d435c.jpg",
    },{
      name: "appended_file_2.png",
      size: 620888,
      type: "image/png",
      file: "http://localhost/datacapture/evt/media_src/Avg_rain_fall-58bfd786d435d.jpg",
   }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `data-jfiler-files='<?php echo json_encode($dummyarr1);?>'`

Comment: Code-only answers do very little to educate SO readers.  Please edit your answer to include some explanation. Your answer is in the moderation queue because it has been flagged as low-quality.